# securestorage ionic not access after record

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile

i read [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage), check this [code](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/blob/master/securestorage_ionicnative/app/pages/home/home.ts), here too [Sample](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/08/16/working-with-ionic-native-using-secure-storage/) and i fail always. :(.
This is my code:

```
export class HomePage {
 private secureStorage: SecureStorage;
 private data: SecureStorageObject;
 private msg: string;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, 
 private toast: ToastController) {
if (platform.is('cordova')) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {

    this.secureStorage = new SecureStorage();
    this.secureStorage.create('demoapp').then(
      (storage: SecureStorageObject) => {
        this.toast.create({message: 'Storage is ready!',position: 'bottom', duration: 3000}).present();
        this.data = storage;
        this.data.set('teste','chave')
          .then(
            data => {
              this.setMsg("gravou");
              this.toast.create({message: "enable ="+this.msg,position: 'bottom', duration: 3000}).present();
              this.data.get('teste')
                .then(
                  data => {
                    this.setMsg(data);
                    this.toast.create({message: "content="+this.msg,position: 'bottom', duration: 3000}).present();
                  },
                  error => {
                    // do nothing - it just means it doesn't exist
                  }
                );
            },
            error => {
              // do nothing - it just means it doesn't exist
            }
          );
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  });
} else {
  this.toast.create({message: "not enable",position: 'bottom', duration: 3000}).present();
}
}
setMsg(msg: string) {
  this.msg = msg;
}

getMsg(){
  return this.data.get('teste');
}

showData() {
  this.toast.create({message: "show ="+this.getMsg(),position: 'bottom', duration: 3000}).present();
}
```

This code above return the Key correctly when running toast inside ".then(...)". But, when tried access in other place, like showData(), not work, return "undefined".

Why "this.data = storage" not working outside of "create('demoapp').then(...)"?

How can access in others pages this key stored in 'demmoapp' ?

If has one tutorials which can i follow to fixed, please share with me.
I was start now with ionic, start studying angular and ionic but i did not ready for this issue.

Running on:

```
#ng -v
Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest" 


    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic


@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.35
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.8.1

#ionic -v
3.20.0
```

all in one mac os x sierra.

Thks

Comment: Is there an error, or just no data?

Comment: is returned "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the time to duplicate this issue, so i'll add more to this if I find the time.

I do notice that you're using the variable data twice, in the same scope.

You should change the variable names when nesting promises.

```
    this.data.set('teste','chave')
      .then(
        data => {

          // !! FIRST DEFINITION OF DATA  ^^   

          this.setMsg("gravou");
          this.toast.create({message: "enable ="+this.msg,position: 'bottom', duration: 3000}).present();
          this.data.get('teste')
            .then(
              data => {

                // !! SECOND DEFINITION OF DATA ^^

                this.setMsg(data);
                this.toast.create({message: "content="+this.msg,position: 'bottom', duration: 3000}).present();
              },
              error => {
                // do nothing - it just means it doesn't exist
              }
            );
        },
        error => {
          // do nothing - it just means it doesn't exist
        }
      );
```

Also, are you debugging this? Are you stepping through your code?

Comment: I changed the variable names like you suggested, same error. How i'm using storage, my test is directly on my cellphone android. I'm using webstorm, how can i debbuger with him?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to debug on android, but just do it in the browser. Run 'ionic serve' and add a debugger statement after the first 'data' promise value. Then inspect in whichever browser you are using.

Comment: I give up, not found in internet nothing to help me. I found this (http://www.cloudypoint.com/Tutorials/discussion/ionic-framework-solved-how-to-open-the-secure-settings-of-the-android-phone-with-my-ionic-2-app/) but not working. I will change to localstorage. Thanks